# How to write the Kibana Timelion expression to get an average time of Celery task execution

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk, timelion

I'm using `ELK` of version `7.17`. Running different `Celery` tasks and logging `"Task started"`, `"Task finished"` events to the `Elasticsearch` via `Logstash`. I'm adding a `trace_id` field as `log_extra`, so, I can recognize pairs related to single task. I want to get an average time spent per `task_type` and how did it change in specified period?
I read it's possible with `Timelion`, but everything I tried fails... is it possible at all?

**UPD 1:**

Example documents:

```
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-05-23T06:01:01.111Z",
  "message": "Task started",
  "trace_id": "1",
  "task_type": "A"
}     
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-05-23T06:02:02.222Z",
  "message": "Task started",
  "trace_id": "2",
  "task_type": "A"
}     
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-05-23T06:03:03.333Z",
  "message": "Task finished",
  "trace_id": "2",
  "task_type": "A"
}
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-05-23T06:04:04.444Z",
  "message": "Task started",
  "trace_id": "3",
  "task_type": "B"
}     
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-05-23T06:05:05.555Z",
  "message": "Task finished",
  "trace_id": "1",
  "task_type": "A"
}     
{
  "@timestamp": "2023-05-23T06:06:06.666Z",
  "message": "Task finished",
  "trace_id": "3",
  "task_type": "B"
}
```

In this example we have 3 `Celery` tasks of 2 types - **"A"** and **"B"**. First task **"A"** with **trace_id=1** start and write log message *"Task started"*, then another task of type **"A"** (**trace_id=2**) start and finish until the end of the first task. Then a third task of type **"B"**(**trace_id=3**) start and will be finished only after the first task will finish.

Comment: Would you mind sharing documents sample of what you have ? And what you tried ?

Comment: @Paulo hi, thank you for answering me. I updated description.